# Function InStr not returning result

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Good afternoon everyone.

I'm writing an webscraping program where I should get all the hyperlinks of a page and check if a pre-determined id of material is contained in the hyperlink, if so, my program should open this link. I used the same logic using selenium+python but translating it to vba is giving me headaches.

The program is

```
plataforma.Refresh
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Set allLinks = plataforma.FindElementsByTag("a")
For Each link2 In allLinks:
    link = link2.Attribute("href")
    Debug.Print link
    compara = InStr(1, link, idmaterial, vbTextCompare)
    Debug.Print idmaterial
    Debug.Print compara
Next
```

And the result of it is in the print:
[image]

As the "idmaterial" is contained in the link the variable "compara" should return something different from 0, right? What is exactly that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you perhaps `Trim$` the `idmaterial`? Maybe a trailing space or something?

Comment: How is `compara` declared?

Comment: Actually looks like a leading space from the screenshot.

Comment: Please check your debug.print output so that the lines match the order of the debug .print statements in your code

Comment: @Bigben - that "leading space" may be because the value is numeric.  If you compare (eg) `? 4` and `? "4"` you'll see there's a difference between text and numeric values in the Immediate output.

Comment: @TimWilliams - oh good to know, TIL.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in that posted code which could explain the results you're getting.

Comment: Maybe to try and break it down, cut & paste the immediate window output and hard-code link and idmaterial as strings (eg "63947", and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Qharr compara is declared as integer

Comment: @BigBen thanks a lot, the `Trim` function on the variable `idmaterial` worked just fine. Now I can proceed with my project. Thanks